# Propiedad position me genera un scroll

Tags: html5, css3, position

Hago que el elipse del fondo quede cortado hacia la derecha:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con las propiedades

```
<span class="decoration-background-hero">
      <img src="./images/bg-tablet-pattern.svg" alt="">
    </span>
```

```
.decoration-background-hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: -110px;
  right: -120px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Pero me genera un scroll así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría hacer para que me no me genere ese scroll, si se hace lo mismo hacia el lado izquierda no se genera ningún scroll, porque nose pero hacia la izquierda nada genera scroll.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

o

```
overflow: hidden
```

a

```
.decoration-background-hero.
```

Comment: No funciona! Esta se genera frecuentemente hacia la izquiera no más.

Comment: mmm lo que yo haría seria colocar un `div` fuera de `span` así `<div class="decoration-background-hero"><span>
      <img src="./images/bg-tablet-pattern.svg" alt="">
    </span></div>`. Ademas de esto coloca `overflow: hidden` en el estilo de `.decoration-background-hero` .

Comment: Recuerdo que este tutorial me ayudó mucho a entender como se usa `overflow: hidden`, como una especie de marco que se le coloca a secciones del html, a este marco si se le puede quitar los scrolls laterales. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oP5472drWiI